# Validate access jwt token before each route, if not valid, logout in vue-cli

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, vue-cli

I have some guard for checking access token before each route and it seams is not working, in console i get from token validator "Access Denied! Unauthorized User" but it does nothing.. i want if token is invalid or expired to logout and destroy the token and redirect to login page.. see my code below. Im new with this and im learning from scratch so.. any solutions are welcome. Thanks guys!

router.js

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  
  const publicPages = [
    '/pages/login', 
    '/pages/register', 
    '/pages/forgot-password', 
    '/pages/comingsoon', 
    '/pages/error-404', 
    '/pages/error-500', 
    '/pages/not-authorized', 
    '/pages/maintenance', 
    '/callback'
  ]
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path)
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')

  // trying to access a restricted page + not logged in
  // redirect to login page
  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    next('/pages/login')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
const guard = function (to, from, next) {
  // check for valid auth token
  axios.get('http://localhost:8081/api/users/checkAuthToken').then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    // Token is valid, so continue
    next()
  }).catch(error => {
    // There was an error so redirect
    
    console.log(error)
    window.location.href = '/pages/login'
     localStorage.removeItem('userInfo')
     localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
  })
}
```

checkAuthToken code:

```
checktkn: (req, res) => {
   
    let token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken') 
    if (token) {
       
      // Remove Bearer from string
      token = token.slice(7)
      sign.verify(token, 'qwe1234', (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.json({
            success: 0,
            message: 'Invalid Token...'
          })
        } else {
          req.decoded = decoded 
        }
      })
    } else {
      return res.json({
        success: 0,
        message: 'Access Denied! Unauthorized User'
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try using `res.status(401)` instead of `res.json` when the token is not valid, in this way the backend responds with an http error when the token is not valid and the `catch` in the axios call will make sense. Right now axios get always a 200 response and never enter the `catch` block

Comment: the thing is , when is valid, and i don';t know why it says i have no access

Comment: Probably because you do not respond to the client after `req.decoded = decoded`, add here `res.json("Valid token")`... Also add `.end()` after every `res.status` or `res.json` call: `res.json("Valid token").end()`

Comment: still not working.. can u make me an example of code if u are kind?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EAFNt4fh

Comment: Thank you @MedaiP90 with a few changes and your code it's working now,best regards!